# Divide year in quarters with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, columnsorting

First of all my data:

```
dput(UmsatzImEinzelhandelQuartalsdaten[1:10,])
structure(list(Name = c("Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg",
"Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg",
"Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg",
"Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Württemberg"), Jahr = c("2012", "2012",
"2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014"
), Quartal = c("1. Quartal", "2. Quartal", "3. Quartal", "4. Quartal",
"1. Quartal", "2. Quartal", "3. Quartal", "4. Quartal", "1. Quartal",
"2. Quartal"), Umsatz = c("101.2", "105", "102.8", "114.5", "100.5",
"104.8", "103.9", "113.5", "101.2", "107.7")), row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need a graph like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOkPy.png with "Umsatz" on the y-axis and "Jahr" on the x-axis. And (most importantly), I don't just need the "Umsatz" per year (summed up), but per year divided in quarters.

Therefore, I wand a new column that combines the columns “Jahr” and “Umsatz” and which I can then use as the x-axis.
Nevertheless, I am only allowed to work with "ggplot2". How do I do that? Unfortunately, I have no idea for a command.

Many thanks
Liv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zoo::as.yearqtr` function

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

UmsatzImEinzelhandelQuartalsdaten %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.yearqtr(paste(Jahr, Quartal), format = "%Y %q. Quartal"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = as.numeric(Umsatz), color = Name)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: @mrs.friday - the (not so explained) trick here is the transformation into a date class. Thus, R (and ggplot2) will recognise it as a Date. You could then also use something like `+ scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months")`

Comment: You are seriously a genius! Thank you! Thank you so much! Works perfectly.! Best regards, Liz.

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks for reminding me. Since I really want to unterstand what I did wrong, I have one question left: How is it possible to divide the columns "Jahr" and "Quartal" into quarters (which I assume we did with the command "yearqtr"). I searched a lot before asking here, and of course  I found the yearqtr command but I does not make any sense to me how this works with two columns.

Comment: @Mrs.Friday this was done with the call to `paste`. you did nothing "wrong"!

Comment: You can use `scale_x_yearqtr` like this: `UmsatzImEinzelhandelQuartalsdaten %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.yearqtr(paste(Jahr, Quartal), format = "%Y %q. Quartal")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = as.numeric(Umsatz), color = Name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Yq%q")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for your comment. So, your additional command ```scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Yq%q")```ensures that the x-axis is divided in quarters and that the data is correspondingly shown in quarters, right?